# I am using ajax and getting a failure but no error message

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using Wordpress 3.5 and making a custom page template to do a database look up.  It is failing and the output is:

> [object Object]: error:

I tried this in jsfiddler but it gave the same error.

The page code is:

```
<?php

// Exit if accessed directly
if ( !defined('ABSPATH')) exit;

/*
Template Name: DBLookup
*/
?>

<script language='JavaScript' type='text/javascript' src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'>
function getlist(form) {
    //alert(form.mname.value);
    //$('#result_table').html(form.mname.value);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'getlist.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {n : form.mname.value},
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(output_string) {
            $('#result_table').html(output_string);
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $('#result_table').html(XMLHttpRequest + ': ' + textStatus + ': '+ errorThrown);
                  }
    } // End of success function of ajax form
    ); // End of ajax call    
}
</script>

<?php get_header(); ?>

        <div id="content" class="grid col-620">

<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        <?php $options = get_option('responsive_theme_options'); ?>
        <?php if ($options['breadcrumb'] == 0): ?>
        <?php echo responsive_breadcrumb_lists(); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

            <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>                

                <?php if ( comments_open() ) : ?>               
                <div class="post-meta">
                <?php responsive_post_meta_data(); ?>

                    <?php if ( comments_open() ) : ?>
                        <span class="comments-link">
                        <span class="mdash">&mdash;</span>
                    <?php comments_popup_link(__('No Comments &darr;', 'responsive'), __('1 Comment &darr;', 'responsive'), __('% Comments &darr;', 'responsive')); ?>
                        </span>
                    <?php endif; ?> 
                </div><!-- end of .post-meta -->
                <?php endif; ?> 

                <div class="post-entry">
                    <?php the_content(__('Read more &#8250;', 'responsive')); ?>
                    <?php wp_link_pages(array('before' => '<div class="pagination">' . __('Pages:', 'responsive'), 'after' => '</div>')); ?>
                </div><!-- end of .post-entry -->


                <?php if ( comments_open() ) : ?>
                <div class="post-data">
                    <?php the_tags(__('Tagged with:', 'responsive') . ' ', ', ', '<br />'); ?> 
                    <?php the_category(__('Posted in %s', 'responsive') . ', '); ?> 
                </div><!-- end of .post-data -->
                <?php endif; ?>             

            <div class="post-edit"><?php edit_post_link(__('Edit', 'responsive')); ?></div> 
            </div><!-- end of #post-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->

            <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?> 

        <?php if (  $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 ) : ?>
        <div class="navigation">
            <div class="previous"><?php next_posts_link( __( '&#8249; Older posts', 'responsive' ) ); ?></div>
            <div class="next"><?php previous_posts_link( __( 'Newer posts &#8250;', 'responsive' ) ); ?></div>
        </div><!-- end of .navigation -->
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php else : ?>

        <h1 class="title-404"><?php _e('404 &#8212; Fancy meeting you here!', 'responsive'); ?></h1>
        <p><?php _e('Don&#39;t panic, we&#39;ll get through this together. Let&#39;s explore our options here.', 'responsive'); ?></p>
        <h6><?php _e( 'You can return', 'responsive' ); ?> <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Home', 'responsive' ); ?>"><?php _e( '&larr; Home', 'responsive' ); ?></a> <?php _e( 'or search for the page you were looking for', 'responsive' ); ?></h6>
        <?php get_search_form(); ?>

<?php endif; ?>  

        <div>

<form name="DBLookup" action="javascript:void(0);">
Full or partial malware name<br>
<input style="width: 350px;" type="text" name="dataname" id="mname">
<input type="submit" name="submit" onClick="getlist(this.form);">
</form>
<div id='result_table'></div>
          </div>  


        </div><!-- end of #content -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

getlist.php is simply:

```
<?php
echo "got it";
?>
```

Comment: Try outputting `XMLHttpRequest.status` and `XMLHttpRequest.statusText`. If the `status` is 0 then a network issue is preventing you from connecting.

Comment: Is the response visible in the console? that would give you a proper status code.

Comment: I found the response in the console: "..is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin."

Comment: See this post for your answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143093/origin-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin

Comment: That worked perfectly!  Thank you!  Are there any security implications for doing this?  Also, can you post that as an official answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Why would that be causing a problem in this code? There's no domain in the URL, so it's not cross-origin.